# How to implement Authorization Code Grant in Azure

Tags: reactjs, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am trying to understand how to implement Authorization Code Grant in Azure. I am not sure if my understanding is the correct implementation to it but here it goes. I have 2 app service in Azure(1 for my API and another 1 use to hold my Reactjs application where it has the user interface).  For me to secure my Api, I am planning to implement Authorization Code Grant.

Based on my understanding the flow would be like this:

1. In my SPA I need to check first if user is authenticated, if not I need to redirect the user to:

   [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize)?
   client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
   &response_type=code
   &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
   &response_mode=query
   &scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read
   &state=12345
2. Once the user granted it should return a authorization code
3. (This part is a little bit confusing to me). Since I am just using Javascript(ReactJS), I think its not safe to store my client secret in my code. So I am thinking is passing the Autorization Code to my API and inside my API it will contact the Token end point

   // Line breaks for legibility only

   POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
   Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

   client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
   &scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read
   &code=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq3n8b2JRLk4OxVXr...
   &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
   &grant_type=authorization_code
   &client_secret=JqQX2PNo9bpM0uEihUPzyrh
4. What should be my next step? Since I got the Access Token does it mean I can give now the data?

I read an article that "Implicit grant flow" is for SPA but its old and no longer secure. I am not sure should I use "Authorization Code Grant" or "Implicit grant flow" given my situation.

Comment: Is there a library in ReactJs to implement authentication of azure?

Answer (score 0):

Recommendations are as follows:

- Use Authorization Code Flow (PKCE) in your SPA
- Use a security library to do the SPA security work for you

In this case a runtime secret is generated and there is no client secret. Maybe these resources of mine will fill in some gaps for you:

- [Code Sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.azure)
- [Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2017/11/30/azure-active-directory-setup/)

Comment: Sorry I havent tried PKCE but is that a paid service? Any good recommendation for Library?

Comment: It's just a pattern that security libraries will implement for you by default - no costs - here is the [relevant code](https://github.com/gary-archer/authguidance.websample.azure/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts)